# Password protected existing aws hosted non-static website

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudfront

What's the best way and steps to password protect an existing non-static website hosted on AWS? We are using an ALB. It will use a single password entered on a simple form before landing on the homepage if authenticated.

Comment: I'm open to suggestions on how to do this. Would be useful if the reason for the downvote is explained

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Amazon Cognito](https://aws.amazon.com/cognito/) to secure web applications with users defined in User Pools. For information, see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-identity-pools.html.